# rails heroku Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound (Failed to find Chrome binary.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, heroku

I have been smashing my head against the wall as I can't get this to work. I have a rails app running on heroku where I want to do some scraping. On my local machine everything works fine.

 
This is my Rails scraper:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.binary = ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN']

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
driver.get "https://www.google.com"
puts driver.title
driver.quit
```

This is what I have done on heroku:

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
heroku config:set GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome 
heroku config:set GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM=/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

however, after some digging I saw that both GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN & GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM are always being overwritten by heroku I guess, they always look like this when exposed:

```
GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome 
GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM=/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

I also tried to set the a custom GOOGLE_PATH to `/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome`, after reading the [official repo for the build pack][1]. But that didn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the complete set of things I did to get this working on Heroku in July of 2022, for an app using the `heroku-20` stack.

First, I added the following three buildpacks:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/chromedriver
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/google-chrome
```

This means the app now uses four buildpacks, the above three and the default `heroku/ruby` one.

To check this has worked, ensure that you are now seeing a value being returned for `ENV["GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN"]` (as well as `ENV["GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM"]`).

Next, I set up my `config/initializers/capybara.rb`:

```rb
binary = ENV.fetch("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN", nil)

Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = binary if binary

Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
  options = {
    args: %w[headless no-sandbox disable-dev-shm-usage disable-gpu remote-debugging-port=9222],
    binary: binary
  }.compact_blank
  
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(options)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, capabilities: capabilities)
end
```

Remember to ensure you're using the `:headless_chrome` driver when you are doing your scraping, e.g. by setting `Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome` in your initializer, or by declaring it explicitly when you start a new Capybara session: `Capybara::Session.new(:headless_chrome)`.

Lastly, I created an empty `Aptfile` in my rails app's root folder, which is necessary for the `heroku-community/apt` buildpack to work.